# How to get the image from bucket to preview it to the user

Tags: php, json, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am working on Google Cloud Storage in which I am trying to crop and upload an image. In this I've uploaded the image and fetching it back to crop it. I have used following methods to do  so:

**Method 1:**

```
$options = ['gs_bucket_name' => $my_bucket];
$upload_url = CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload/handler', $options);
```

using [these](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/user_upload) docs. But in this I get class not found. I tried including the file for example:

```
require_once APPPATH."google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php"; 

$options = ['size' => 400, 'crop' => true];
$image_file = "gs://my_bucket/shiva.jpg";
$cloud_tools = new CloudStorageTools;
$img = $cloud_tools->getImageServingUrl($image_file, $options);
```

but the I get class not found for

```
use google\appengine\CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKeyRequest;
```

ans etc. I checked the `CreateEncodedGoogleStorageKeyRequest` under the appengine folder. I found it missing there. I don't know whats going on.

**Method 2:**
I tried uploading the file using the following code.

```
function upload_user_image($image_file, $bucket_name = ''){
$client = google_set_client();
$storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
$sfilename = $image_file['name']; //filename here
$obj = new Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();

$obj->setName($sfilename);
$obj->setBucket("my_bucket"); //bucket name here


$filen = $image_file['path'];

$mimetype = mime_content_type($filen);


$chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
$client->setDefer(true);
$status = false;

$filetoupload = array('name' => $sfilename, 'uploadType' => 'resumable');

$request = $storage->objects->insert("my_bucket",$obj,$filetoupload);

$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload($client, $request, $mimetype, null, true, $chunkSizeBytes);
$media->setFileSize(filesize($filen));
$handle = fopen($filen, "rb");

while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

$result = false;
if($status != false) {
    $result = $status;
}

fclose($handle);
// Reset to the client to execute requests immediately in the future.
$client->setDefer(false);
return true;
```

}

I got succeed in uploading the image using above code but now stuck in getting the image and previewing it in html. (I want to crop the image and then upload again). For which I tried following:

**Method a:**

```
$image = file_get_contents("https://storage.cloud.google.com/my_bucket/shiva.jpg");
echo $image;
```

using [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-uris). In which I get a login box in my html where I fill my Google credentials and get redirected to image. But don't get the image preview in my html code.

**Method b:**
I tried

```
https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_bucket/o/shiva.jpg
```

using [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/get). But I get output :

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "required",
    "message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object my_bucket/shiva.jpg.",
    "locationType": "header",
    "location": "Authorization"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object my_bucket/shiva.jpg."
 }
}
```

**Method c:**
I tried it using the following function:

```
function get_user_image($image_file){
  $instance = &get_instance();
  // $client = google_set_client();
  // $storage = new Google_Service_Storage($client);
  $sfilename = $image_file; //filename here

  $storage = new Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient(['projectId' => $instance->config->item('google_project_id')]);
  $bucket = $storage->bucket('my_bucket');
  $object = $bucket->object($sfilename);

  $stream = $object->downloadAsString();
  $im = imagecreatefromstring($stream);
  if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
  }
  else {
    echo 'An error occurred.';
  }
}
```

using [these docs](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/v0.20.2/storage/storageobject)

I am stuck fro last three days. I need to display the image to user in html. Please anyone guide me what am I missing? Please give the proper way to accomplish this.

Comment: What error did you get with method C?

Comment: Hi @BrandonYarbrough thanks for the response. In case of method C. I am able to display the image in browser window but not with html. In html I get this `image/file can not be displayed it contains errors`. Whereas If I put `exit()` after this function being called. It displays me the image.

Comment: Are these anonymously viewable images? Why just use a basic image like `<IMG SRC="https://BUCKET_NAME.storage.googleapis.com/imageName.jpeg">`?

Comment: No actually when I run this url it gives me xml object `<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access denied.</Message><Details>Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to object my_bucket/shiva.jpg.</Details></Error`

Comment: You haven't made the object publicly accessible. Try granting allUsers read permission: `gsutil acl ch -g allUsers:R gs://my_bucket/shiva.jpg` (assuming it's okay if anyone views it).

Comment: Okay I'll give it a try. Won't it be insecure or something like that if grant them publicly accessible permission? and Do we have to grant this permission to each image that is being uploaded?

Comment: Oh absolutely! If you don't want any anonymous user to be able to download each image, then this solution won't work for you at all. If you are comfortable having them be anonymously viewable, then you can change the bucket's default ACL to allow readers for every new object created, or you can specify that allUsers have read permission as you upload each new object.

Comment: Yeyyyyyyy! The solution worked. Thanks a lot @BrandonYarbrough. Please post this solution as an aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are comfortable with these objects being anonymously visible, the easiest solution to display them as images on a website would be simply to mark them as publicly accessible and then to embed them in HTML like so:

```
<IMG SRC="https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/imageName.jp‌​eg" />
```

Comment: Hey @brandon Now I am trying to upload image to bucket by cropping it. But when I try to upload the cropped image then I get this error: "HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections". I am not able to understand whats going on? why am I getting this error. Would you please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you're using file_put_contents with an HTTP URL?

Comment: No I am using function `imagejpeg($file_content,$destination_path)`. It is giving this error. Where destination path is the same as that I am fetching from cloud storage.