# Getting error :- "HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections" while uploading the cropped image to google cloud storage

Tags: php, image, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have checked for this error all over the google. But couldn't find any useful answer.

I am trying to upload image to bucket by cropping it for which I have followed following approach. you can check my code in this post ([How to get the image from bucket to preview it to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42223552/how-to-get-the-image-from-bucket-to-preview-it-to-the-user)).

1. I uploaded the image on bucket.
2. Fetched the image from bucket.
3. Cropped the image.
4. And then upload the image again to bucket

.

Above 1 to 3 points are successfully done. But when I try to upload the cropped image then I get this error: "HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections". I am not able to understand whats going on? why am I getting this error. Can you please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: That message usually pops up when you're trying to use a normal PHP stream writer to write to a URL stream. If step 1 is done correctly then make sure you're doing step 4 the same way.

Comment: Hi @apokryfos, Actually If I have to use step 1 to accomplish this. Then I have to save the image locally on user's system. Where there can be a permission problem or can be a different platform (windows, ubuntu etc.). So I am unable to do it that way.